# JQuery Mobile Range Slider CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Looking for a way to hide/remove the "square boxes" indicated by the arrows in the below picture for the JQuery Mobile range slider:

[image: jquery]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
.ui-slider-track .ui-btn.ui-slider-handle {
    display: none;
}
```

That is if you are referring to this jQuery https://api.jquerymobile.com/rangeslider/.